# htaccess force https with 301 redirect but found that it's actually 302

Tags: laravel, .htaccess, redirect, https, cloudflare

**[Update]**

I activated Always use HTTPS and now it redirects twice to 301 (first is https and second is http )then to 200 (https) but still don't know why this redirection happens

[image]

---

I have a problem when I check my website using [https://www.redirectcheck.com](http://redirectcheck.com/) it displays that the redirect to 301 then to 302 then status is 200. This happens when this page isn't in public cache control but when it's publicly cached it gets to status 200 directly. This is a Laravel project connected to cloudflare with this in root .htaccess

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www.example.com$
RewriteRule ^(.*) https://example.com/$1  [QSA,L,R=301]

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

#remove 'public/' from the url
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} (\.\w+$) [NC]
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ public/$1

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ server.php [L]
</IfModule>
```

And this .htaccess inside public folder

```
<IfModule mod_rewrite.c>
<IfModule mod_negotiation.c>
    Options -MultiViews
</IfModule>

RewriteEngine On

# Redirect Trailing Slashes If Not A Folder...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule ^(.*)/$ /$1 [L,R=301]

# Handle Front Controller...
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteRule ^ index.php [L]

# Handle Authorization Header
RewriteCond %{HTTP:Authorization} .
RewriteRule .* - [E=HTTP_AUTHORIZATION:%{HTTP:Authorization}]
RewriteEngine On
RewriteCond %{SERVER_PORT} 80
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_URI} folder
RewriteRule ^(.*)$ https://example.com/$1 [R,L]
</IfModule>
```

And routes middleware

```
Route::middleware('cache.headers:public')->group(function() {
```

Cloudflare:

[image]

[image]

Why does it say that redirect is 302 not 301 and how would that affect SEO?

```
example.com

HTTP/1.1 302 Found
Date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 20:37:43 GMT
Content-Type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
Transfer-Encoding: chunked
Connection: keep-alive
Set-Cookie: xxxx; expires=Wed, 25-Nov-20 20:37:43 GMT; path=/; 
domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
X-Powered-By: PHP/7.4.6
Cache-Control: no-cache, private
Location: https://example.com
CF-Cache-Status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: xxxx
Report-To: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=xxxx"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
NEL: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
Server: cloudflare
CF-RAY: xxxx

https://example.com

HTTP/2 200 
date: Mon, 26 Oct 2020 20:37:45 GMT
content-type: text/html; charset=UTF-8
set-cookie: xxxx; expires=Wed, 25-Nov-20 20:37:43 GMT; path=/; 
domain=.example.com; HttpOnly; SameSite=Lax
x-powered-by: PHP/7.4.6
cache-control: public
set-cookie: hide_cookie_bar=1; expires=Wed, 25-Nov-2020 20:37:44 GMT; Max- 
Age=2592000; path=/
set-cookie: XSRF-TOKEN=xxxx; expires=Mon, 26-Oct-2020 22:37:44 GMT; Max- 
Age=7200; path=/
set-cookie: laravel_session=xxxx; expires=Mon, 26-Oct-2020 22:37:44 GMT; Max- 
Age=7200; path=/; httponly
vary: Accept-Encoding
cf-cache-status: DYNAMIC
cf-request-id: xxxx
expect-ct: max-age=604800, report-uri="https://report-uri.cloudflare.com/cdn-cgi/beacon/expect-ct"
report-to: {"endpoints":[{"url":"https:\/\/a.nel.cloudflare.com\/report?s=xxxx"}],"group":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
nel: {"report_to":"cf-nel","max_age":604800}
server: cloudflare
cf-ray: xxxx
```

Comment: I did but nothing changed. This happen for certain URLs in the website not all URLs which is confusing me. It loads the https version then redirects to http then redirects back again to https

Comment: It it happens for certain URLs then it is certainly not due to your rules. It might be either some caching or your framework.

Comment: I noticed that setting cache control to public for certain pages, when I open any of them it gets redirected to 301 then 302 then 200. When I reload the same page it just displays 200 directly which means setting cache for the first time may be the cause don't know if I'm correct!!

Comment: Post has been updated with screenshots if you can help.

Comment: Thanks for providing all details. Unfortunately I have no knowledge of cloudflare to assist further. Hope some expert helps you further.

Comment: Thanks for your help so far I really appreciate it.